# Prestashop API request POST product returns CODE 97

Tags: rest, api, prestashop-1.6

Prestashop 1.6.1.10 and 1.6.1.4

Hi, I'm trying to do something so simple as adding a new product using the Prestashop REST API Post request.

I send a POST request to http://url_to_website.com/api/products/?schema=blank with the XML message and get the back a lot of SQL queries that can't exec properly because they are missing some obvious parameters in the where statements. I don't know anything about how Prestashop works for me it seems strange that I would even need to launch these queries for a POST request. If anyone can spread some light on this I would be very happy.

```
2016/12/02 20:38:51 - Write to log.0 - httpstat = 500
2016/12/02 20:38:51 - Write to log.0 - Result = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<errors>
<error>
<code><![CDATA[97]]></code>
<message><![CDATA[[SQL Error] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3. From ProductAdd->hookactionProductSave() Query was : 
            SELECT *
            FROM ps_product_lang
            WHERE id_product=]]></message>
</error>
<error>
<code><![CDATA[97]]></code>
<message><![CDATA[[SQL Error] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'limit 1' at line 3. From ProductAdd->hookactionProductSave() Query was : 
            SELECT *
            FROM ps_stock_available
            WHERE id_product= limit 1]]></message>
</error>
<error>
<code><![CDATA[97]]></code>
<message><![CDATA[[SQL Error] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'limit 1' at line 3. From ProductAdd->hookactionProductSave() Query was : 
            SELECT *
            FROM ps_product
            WHERE id_product= limit 1]]></message>
</error>
<error>
<code><![CDATA[97]]></code>
<message><![CDATA[[SQL Error] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'limit 1' at line 3. From ProductAdd->hookactionProductSave() Query was : 
            SELECT *
            FROM ps_product_carrier
            WHERE id_product= limit 1]]></message>
</error>
<error>
<code><![CDATA[97]]></code>
<message><![CDATA[[SQL Error] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3. From ProductAdd->hookactionProductSave() Query was : 
            SELECT *
            FROM ps_image
            WHERE id_product=]]></message>
</error>
</errors>
</prestashop>
```

Answer (score 0):

`POST` method must be used just for create entities (add). If you want to retreive an empty product using `schema=blank` you should use GET method.

I recommend you to use Prestashop API library: [here](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Using+the+PrestaShop+Web+Service)

Good luck.